# How can I build my project with Android NDK on windows?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, cygwin

I try to run my project in windows. Project use android ndk.  I install Cygwin and add "C:\cygwin\bin" in PATH. Instal GnuMake, and set variable GNUMAKE = /cygdrive/c/Art/GnuMake/bin/make.exe. Also I add native support to my project in Eclipse.
When I try run this project, Eclipse Show:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project FFWall ****

C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe C:\Art\android-ndk\ndk-build V=1 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ERROR: Your GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name: /cygdrive/c/Art/GnuMake/bin/make.exe
Please fix it to point to a valid make executable (e.g. /usr/bin/make)

**** Build Finished ****
```

How I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the GNU's Make.exe, try the make.exe present in the Cygwin's bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNUMAKE = C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe   It`s working for me